# React router receives match params but does not update the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga, reselect

I'm using react-boilerplate for my project. When changing the router param, the component does not rerender. The router looks like this.

```
<switch>
  <route exact path="/" render={()><homepage {...this.props}/> } />
  <route exact path="/practice-areas" component={PracticeAreasLandingPage}/>
  <route path="/practice-areas/:practiceAreasItem" component={PracticeAreas}/>} />
  <route component={ notfoundpage } />
</switch>
```

The component looks like this.

```
        class PracticeArea extends PureComponent {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            this.props.onInit();
        }
        render() {
            const pa = this.props.practiceArea;
            const randPas = this.props.randPracticeAreas;
        .... 
            export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
            return {
                onInit: () => {
                dispatch(loadPracticeArea());
                dispatch(loadRandomPracticeAreas());
                }
            };
            }
            const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
            practiceArea: makeSelectPracticeArea(),
            loading: makeSelectLoading(),
            error: makeSelectError(),
            randPracticeAreas: makeSelectRandomPracticeAreas(),
            randLoading: makeSelectRandomLoading(),
            randError: makeSelectRandomError(),
            });
            const withConnect = connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps,
            );
            const withReducer = injectReducer({
            key: 'practiceArea',
            reducer
            });
            const withSaga = injectSaga({
            key: 'practiceArea',
            saga
            });
            export default compose(
            withReducer,
            withSaga,
            withConnect,
            )(PracticeArea);
```

When clicking on a Link that has a route like '/practice-areas/some-route', the component does not update.

Comment: Post router and link code.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `PracticeAreas` Route before the `PracticeAreasLandingPage` Route

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={()><homepage {...this.props}/> } />
  <Route path="/practice-areas/:practiceAreasItem" component={PracticeArea} />
  <Route path="/practice-areas" component={PracticeAreasLandingPage}/>
  <Route component={ NotFoundPage } />
</Switch>
```

Order of `Routes` is important in a `Switch` component, since it goes down the list to find a `path` that is satisfied by the `url`.

If you navigate to `localhost:3000/practice-areas/123` and the `PracticeAreasLandingPage` Route comes before `PracticeArea`, you still satisfy the necessary condition for `PracticeAreasLandingPage` which is just "`practice-areas`" so Switch ends up rendering that first. And since you are already on that route to begin with, it gives the appearance that nothing was updated.

Swapping the position of the two Routes would resolve this because now you're telling `Switch` to go down the list and check whether the `url`, `localhost:3000/practice-areas/123` satisfies the path for `PracticeArea` `"/practice-areas/:practiceAreasItem"` first.

Comment: I've tried that already. I'm sorry, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @VahagnSargsyan weird, can you post the code with the `Link` that navigates to this component?

Comment: Also, does this component ever render if you go directly to it without navigating from a Link?

Comment: Yes, actually I found a solution. I just add a lifecycle componentWillReceiveProps method and as I get match.params from react-router, I dispatch an event which gets the data from db and passes it to the component through props.

Comment: @VahagnSargsyan thats awesome! Yeah with the code your provided I would have never have thought that was an issue :)

Comment: thank you :) it's just the way react-boilerplate works